# EF works but I can't find the database (but only in the test environment)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

My three environments are all acting differently.

EF came with my chosen MVC website project template and I haven't messed with it. I do have a mdf file in my `App_Data` folder. The location and filename were determine by the nuget installer I assume. Identity framework uses it. To give you some context.

My `web.config` ef connection string is:

```xml
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-AACOMvc-20160730112925.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-AACOMvc-20160730112925;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is the connection string provided by the template / installer whatever.

**Local Machine**

It works. If I mess with the connection string or the mdf filename, it breaks. So I know it's hitting that file.

**Test Environment**

It works. Funny because I don't publich the `App_Data` folder! I have searched all over that box looking for the mdf (it created?) but there is not one. If I comment out the connection string in the web.config, it still works! It's being "smart" and "sneaky" and I don't like it! :)

**Production Environment**

It doesn't work. Even if I copy over the App_Data folder, it still will fail with "file not found" error.

This question is focusing on the test environment. If I can find out how it's working, I think I will be closer to getting it to working in production.

Comment: Have you checked your user profile folder? C:\Users\user-name https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database/

Comment: @SteveGreene, [warning: stupidity ahead] I remoted in and tried but it had no subfolders, just pseudo subfolders like "documents". A search from the root of C for *.mdf yielded nothing. Also, would IIS be a user folder as well? Which user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recall I fixed this by changing the EF connection string to a sql server instance instead of a sql server file. EF didn't even create any tables in the database b/c I don't have any entities defined.